# how to install ros packages?

Tags: hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi guys.

i'm beginner about ros.
i wanna use some ros packages.
for example i wanna use hector slam.
but i don't know how to install its source file from github.

or i don't know how to install hector slam expect for using github.

please help me for solving this problem.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225538/how-to-install-ros-packages?/) by [yoneyama1027](https://answers.ros.org/users/25796/yoneyama1027/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-02-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The easiest and preferred way of installing packages is via

```
$ sudo apt-get install ros-<your distro>-<package name>
```

like e.g.

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-hector-slam
```

If there is no debian build or you need the source version for some reason you clone the Github repo to the `src` folder of your catkin workspace.

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2016-02-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yoneyama1027](https://answers.ros.org/users/25796/yoneyama1027/) on 2016-02-01**:
thanks a lot!
i try it soon!

**Comment by [skr_robo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25555/skr_robo/) on 2016-07-19**:
If the debian binary package is available, you should follow **BennyRe**'s answer, else you should follow **RoSPlebb**'s answer. One thing to be careful while using the git clone command is to specify the branch if required.